# Python map method on multi-input methods

Tags: python

In Python we have the `map` method that allows us to perform a callable on each element of an iterable. Example:

```
requests = map(create_update_request, locations)
```

This is quite easy (although some argue it's more "pythonic" to use list comprehensions, I'd say it depends on the use-case). However, to my knowledge, `map` only works if it's single-input methods, e.g.

```
def create_update_request(location_id: int):
    ...

locations = [1, 2, 3]

requests = map(create_update_request, locations)
```

What if the callable we want to parse takes input, that is contained in the iterable through a tuple?

```
def create_update_request(location_id: int, item: dict):
    ...

locations = [(1, {"name": "foo"}),
             (2, {"name": "bar"}),
             (3, {"name": "baz"})]

#requests = map(create_update_request, locations) does not work any more!
requests = [create_update_request(location_id, item) for (location_id, item) in locations] # A
requests = [create_update_request(*args) for args in locations] # B
```

Then we are forced into a list comprehension that triggers everything being loaded to memory. Is there an elegant way around this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools`,

```
from itertools import starmap
requests = starmap(create_update_request, locations)
```

Of course, if the lack of lazy iteration was your concern, you could have always used a generator expression

```
requests = (create_update_request(*args) for args in locations)
```

Comment: This was exactly the one I didn't know of, thanks!